# Adding file to Git repository

Tags: git

I am trying to add a file from Visual Studio Code to Git repository. But whenever I type this code:

```
$ git add index.html
```

I get this message in my terminal:

```
fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files
```

I thought I typed the file name exactly as it was typed in my finder. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to include path to the file.

Comment: See what files *are* there, with `ls`.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory when issuing the command?

Comment: **read the error message**: ...did not match any files -> in this folder you don‘t have a file that called *index.html*

Answer (score 2):

Well, I imagine you are not in the correct folder.
Just go to the folder which contains the file index.html and do these steps:

`git add index.html`

`git commit -m "comment"`

`git push origin master //or whatever branch you are working in`

Comment: It dawned on me when you imagined I was not at the correct folder. I had to open a new terminal at my folder titled web-projects.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

`git status`

This will show you any files that are modified or not yet in the repo (plus other status's), e.g.:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test/test12345.txt   <<< File not yet in the repo
```

Here you can see there is a file to add in a sub-folder called test. So I can do:

```
git add test/test12345.txt
git commit -m "added new file"
```

If you do not see the file that you want to add, check in the `.gitignore` file on the top level of your git repo. It might contain some sort of pattern to ignore the location of type or name of your file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let us assume your project name is myApp then at terminal you should be inside the myApp project and from there if you type **git status** you will get then list of newly added files or new created files from there you add file using command **git add "file name along with directory path"**  but since you are simply adding the file without directory path so you are facing the problem.

I am providing the screenshot as how i have done[image: addFilesTOGit]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory where index.html is located or to the root directory of your project.
issue `git add index.html` command or `git stage index.html` which is equivalent `git add *` for adding all files that have not been added earlier.
Then you can commit and push

```
git commmit -m "Some commit message here"
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

`git add .` (it adds all the files to the staging area)
`git commit -m "message goes here"` (commit the code which is staged)
`git push -u origin master` (push all the committed files to the master branch)

if you want to learn more about git, you can find complete git cheatsheet [here](https://medium.com/@phanendraguptha/git-cheatsheet-b124439bd3f3)